Higher rank tensor analogue of the fact that any matrix is a unique sum of a symmetric and an anti symmetric matrix
We know that any matrix A is the unique sum of a symmetric and an anti-symmetric matrix: simply take $(A+A^T)/2$ and $(A - A^T)/2$. A matrix can be viewed as a (1,1)-Tensor. What about higher order tensors?

Higher-rank tensors can be symmetric or antisymmetric with respect to each pair of components independently, that is why a simple decomposition into purely symmetric and purely antisymmetric tensors as above is not possible in general (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor#Notation).

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$. I will show that such a decomposition for higher order tensors is not possible. Because it is important to introduce and analyze various group actions in studying these tensors, I will work invariantly and consider a tensor as a multilinear map rather than a multidimensional array or matrix.
In your example, instead of choosing coordinates and working with matrices, we could instead work invariantly with elements of $V\otimes V$. Here I am considering the space $V\otimes V$ as the set of all linear maps $V^*\to V$. A pure tensor $v\otimes w\in V\otimes V$ represents the linear map $V^*\to V$ which takes an element $\alpha\in V^*$ to $\alpha(v)w$. If $V$ has a basis $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$, it is readily verified that a basis for $V\otimes V$ is the set $\{v_i\otimes v_j\}$. Note that $GL(V)$ acts on the space $V\otimes V$ via extending its action on pure tensors $g\cdot (v\otimes w) = g\cdot v\otimes g\cdot w$ linearly. Introduce the notation
$$S^2V:= \mathrm{span}\{v_i\otimes v_j+v_j\otimes v_i\mid 1\le i,j\le n\}.$$
This is called the space of symmetric 2-tensors of $V$. Via the equality
$$(v_i+v_j)\otimes (v_i+v_j) = v_i\otimes v_i + v_i\otimes v_j+ v_j\otimes v_i+v_j\otimes v_j,$$
we see that $S^2V = \mathrm{span}\{v\otimes v\mid v\in V\}$. As such, this space is invariant under changes of coordinates: if $g\in GL(V)$ and $T\in S^2V$, then $g\cdot T\in S^2V$ as well. In other words, $S^2V$ is a $GL(V)$-submodule of $V\otimes V$. Likewise, the space
$$\Lambda^2V = \mathrm{span}\{v_i\otimes v_j-v_j\otimes v_i, 1\le i,j\le n\}$$
is the space of skew-symmetric 2-tensors of $V$, and one can check to see that it is also a $GL(V)$-submodule of $V\otimes V$. Indeed, $V\otimes V$ has the $GL(V)$-decomposition $V\otimes V = S^2V\oplus \Lambda^2V$, which mirrors the fact that any matrix is the sum of a symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix.

What about $V^{\otimes 3}$? Does a similar decomposition hold; i.e., do we have $V^{\otimes 3} = S^3V\oplus \Lambda^3V$? Well, first I need to define what I mean by $S^3V$ and $\Lambda^3V$, which could be thought of as generalizations of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices to higher order tensors. Define two maps
$$\pi_S: V^{\otimes d}\to V^{\otimes d}$$
and
$$\pi_{\Lambda} V^{\otimes d}\to V^{\otimes d}$$
as
$$\pi_S(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_d) = \frac1{d!}\sum_{\sigma\in \mathfrak S_d} v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(d)}$$
and
$$\pi_{\Lambda}(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_d) = \frac1{d!}\sum_{\sigma\in \mathfrak S_d} (\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma))v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(d)},$$
where $\mathfrak S_d$ is the symmetric group on $d$ letters and $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ is the sign of the permutation $\sigma$. The images of these projections are denoted $S^dV$ and $\Lambda^dV$, respectively. Note that both of these spaces are also invariant under the action of $GL(V)$. If you are willing to believe me that $\dim(S^dV) = \binom{n+d-1}{n}$ and $\dim(\Lambda^dV) = \binom{n}{d}$, we can conclude if $n>1$, then $V^{\otimes 3} \ne S^3V\oplus \Lambda^3V$ by a dimension count. In fact, if $d>2$, $V^{\otimes d} \ne S^dV\oplus \Lambda^dV$, and the "gap" between the two spaces gets larger as $d$ increases. As such, the answer to the above question is a resounding no.

So, where are all the "missing" tensors that are neither symmetric nor alternating? The full decomposition of $V^{\otimes d}$ as a $GL(V)$-module is achieved via a direct sum of Schur functors indexed by partitions of $d$ with multiplicity. A good resource for this is chapter 6 of JM Landsberg's Tensors: Geometry and Applications. In particular, he states the full decomposition on page 148, theorem 6.4.5.2 (Schur duality). The preliminary result for $V^{\otimes 3}$ is also given on page 52.

Nicely done. Another small point to draw out is that there may not be any antisymmetric tensors at all: If $n<d$, then $\dim(\Lambda^dV) = \binom{n}{d}=0$. (By contrast, there are always symmetric tensors since $n+d-1\geq n\implies \dim(S^dV) = \binom{n+d-1}{n}>0$.)
